# periodical file update in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to periodically check on an input file and update if certain conditions are met.

The following code works fine, but only, if there is at least one session is active. My aim is to update the *acc* dataframe even if there is no active session on ShinyApp.

As it takes 4-5 minutes to load the dataset and would be great to do it overnight, when the file gets updated and not in the morning when the first user opens the application.

```
observe({
invalidateLater(1000000, session)
m.acc <- file.info(accPath)
m.acc.mtime <- m.acc$mtime
# If no change in modtime, do nothing
if (acc.mtime == m.acc.mtime) {
   print('no change in the accounts')
   return(NULL)
} else {
   acc.mtime = m.acc.mtime
   s <- Sys.time()
   acc <- read.csv(accPath)
   l <- Sys.time()
   time<- paste("Data refresh took:",l-s)
   print(time)
  }
 })
```

Temporarily, I leave one session open on the host computer but I'd like to figure out a better way to do so. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure I fully get it. First I would think that without an R script or ShinyApp running you cant have a listener checking for a file!? Or you say I actually only need the update as soon as somebody opens the ShinyApp (because otherwise it cant be seen anyway?) so I want to run the check right before an app is started (which is why i include the check in a global.R file),...

Comment: Sorry for the poor explanation.
Basically, I'd like to update dataframe from the file after the file is updated regardless of any active session on ShinyApp.

Comment: @nrussell  
Could you please review the on-hold status? I have updated the post. Thank you

Comment: I would suggest to use a taskplanner (Windows) / Cron Job (Linux) to periodically run a R skript to check for a new file. If it's new, read it as CSV and save it as a RData file and restart shiny server -> Shiny then is told to read this RData file once it starts.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1: reactivePoll**

One option would be a `reactivePoll`. It has three relevant settings:

1. A polling interval that would be in your case `1000000`.
2. A function to check if the conditions to answer the poll are met. In your case `acc.mtime != m.acc.mtime`.
3. A function to provide the new data.

Forgive me for mocking the business logic with random sampling. The question does not give me all the details I'd need for a complete reprex.

```r
library(shiny)

runApp(list(
  ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Hello Shiny!"),
    # UI CODE
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    UpdateRequired <- function() {
       sample.int(3, 1) # MOCKED CONDITION using a random number to get 66% update chance
    }
    dist <- reactivePoll(1000, session, UpdateRequired, function () {
      ### PUT HERE ANY CODE TO RE-READ YOUR FILE INSTEAD OF CREATING RANDOM NUMBERS
      rnorm(input$obs) # MOCKED "File update": create random numbers instead
    })

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      hist( req(dist()) )
    })
  }
))
```

**Option 2: reactiveFileReader**

The `reactiveFileReader` is even better suited for the job. It "works by periodically checking the file's last modified time; if it has changed, then the file is re-read and any reactive dependents are invalidated" (quote from the manual). So, you do not have to do that by yourself.

Use `reactiveFileReader(intervalMillis, session, filePath, readFunc)` and provide a function for `readFunc`. That "function to use to read the file; must expect the first argument to be the file path to read. The return value of this function is used as the value of the reactive file reader".